# Convert Javascript function to jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have already a short-hand function like so:

```
function myObj() {};
    myObj.prototype.read = function (name) {alert(name);};
    ...(more functions)
```

Now I would like to "convert" this to a jQuery plugin.
What is the best way to do so? (My function doesn't need a selector before it).
I thought about doing it like this:

```
$.myObj.methodHere();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, out of interest? There's no real need to add the extra overhead if you don't need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add your method to the jQuery object.

```
$.myObj = myObj;
```

Then you can call it like:

```
$.myObj.methodHere();
```

EDIT: Why do you want to do this?  jQuery plugins are supposed to act upon jQuery objects.  Your function "doesn't need a selector before it", therefore it's not really a "plugin".

Comment: Although pointless, $.myObj is no diff than calling myObj directly, this is the correct answer

Comment: when I try it firebug throwes this error:
"$.myObj.read() is not a function"

Comment: @agam360: That's because `read` is part of the object's `prototype`, not the object itself.

Comment: Ohh yea I forgot to add the prototype(for the inheretence) "$.myObj= myObj.prototype;" thanks!